# Trying to convert a byte data stream (from RPi Camera) to String (in order to use OpenCV for Image processing)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I am trying to convert a byte type data (stream from RPi over Socket) to string or any useable form (as required by OpenCV); however, unable to do so! I've already tried decoding the received data via io.BytesIO() using .decode() but it comes back saying, JpegImageFile has no Attribute 'decode'. This code works great for PIL but not for OpenCV since the socket returns a byte type data in Python3, and OpenCV requires a numpy array (from what I've read so far). I am using Python 3.5.5, OpenCV 3.4.1... Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import io
import socket
import struct
from PIL import Image
import cv2

server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('10.0.0.214', 8025))
server_socket.listen(0)

connection = server_socket.accept()[0].makefile('rb')
try:
while True:
    image_len = struct.unpack('<L', connection.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
    if not image_len:
        break 
    image_stream = io.BytesIO()
    image_stream.write(connection.read(image_len))

    image_stream.seek(0)
    image = Image.open(image_stream)
    string_data = image.decode()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(string_data, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    print('Image is %dx%d' % image.size)
    image.verify()
    print('Image is verified')
    finally:
connection.close()
server_socket.close()

Traceback (most recent call last):
\test\TestingStream.py", line 32, in <module>
string_data = image.decode()
AttributeError: 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'decode'
[Finished in 11.9s]
```